# How to Remove Lines Not Containing "Emails" in notepad++ or Emeditor

Tags: notepad++, text-editing

how to Remove all lines Not Containing email types in notepad++ or Emeditor

Full example file containing:

```
use1@email.com:password1
user5@email.de:password5
use2@email.net:password2
use3@email.org:password3
use4@email.nl:password4
user1:password1
user2:password2
user3:password3
```

Needed result:

```
use1@email.com:password1
user5@email.de:password5
use2@email.net:password2
use3@email.org:password3
use4@email.nl:password4
```

Comment: You can [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1234314/edit) your question to correct any errors.

Comment: if this is a one-time thing I would just do it in Excel. Paste your data in and apply a "does not contain: email" filter.

Comment: can you prevew a screen ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do the job:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^@]+$`
- Replace with: `EMPTY`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of line
[^@]+       : 1 or more character that is not @
$           : end of line
```

- DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`

**Result for given example:**

```
use1@email.com:password1
user5@email.de:password5
use2@email.net:password2
use3@email.org:password3
use4@email.nl:password4
```